# How to use index match formula in VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to include this index match formula in my VBA script. However, I'm having issues getting it to apply the proper formula to each line. This code adds a new column at AK and then inserts the formula.

```
  Sub test()

     Columns("AK:AK").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

     Range("AK:AK").Value = "=INDEX('[BCHP Group Info Updated.xlsx]Pay to Provider (Edit) (2)'!$J:$J,MATCH(AG1,AG:AG,0))"

End Sub
```

The issue comes in where "MATCH(AG1" would only apply to row one and I need it to continue down for the rest of the data(MATCH(AG2,MATCH(AG3, etc.)
Is there another to reference another worksheet and match the data in order to fill this column? Or perhaps an easier way to do this with an If then statement?

Thanks

Comment: You are attempting to fill the full column with a formula, that will result in errors when AG1 runs out of data.

Comment: **1)** Do you really want to write formulas for the *entire* AK column? Probably not, so only write formulas to the rows you *actually* need **2)** Instead of using `.value` use `.FormulaR1C1` and it will be much easier and fill the formulas with relative references for each row.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I rewritten it to use an if then statement but im having trouble getting the data to input into the cells. `Sub insertcollumns()
a = Worksheets("BCITEXT").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
b = Worksheets("Pay to Provider (Edit) (2)").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("BCITEXT").Cells(i, 33).Value = Worksheets("Pay to Provider (Edit) (2)").Cells(b + 1, 1).Value Then

        Worksheets("BCITEXT").Cells(i, 37).Value = 2
    End If

Next

End Sub`


Would this be a better approach or would using the .formualr1c1 be better?

Comment: Your MATCH must be wrong. If you look for G1 in column G, you're going to get row number 1. Every time; I guarantee it.

Comment: ... and [edit] your question to include additions (especially code) in the question with code in a code block. Posting it in a comment results in a rat's nest.

Comment: @user553936 - FormulaR1C1. One line of code to set for the whole range. Simple and easy.